# How to connect data dictionaries to the unlabeled data

Tags: r, ms-access, data-dictionary

I'm working with some [large government datasets](http://www-odi.nhtsa.dot.gov/downloads/) from the Department of Transportation that are available as tab-delimited text files accompanied by data dictionaries. For example, the auto complaints file is a 670Mb file of unlabeled data (when unzipped), and comes with [a dictionary](http://www-odi.nhtsa.dot.gov/downloads/folders/Complaints/CMPL.txt). Here are some excerpts:

```
Last updated: April 24, 2014

FIELDS:
=======

Field#  Name            Type/Size     Description                      
------  ---------       ---------     --------------------------------------
1       CMPLID          CHAR(9)       NHTSA'S INTERNAL UNIQUE SEQUENCE NUMBER.
                                      IS AN UPDATEABLE FIELD,THUS DATA FOR A
                                      GIVEN RECORD POTENTIALLY COULD CHANGE FROM 
                                      ONE DATA OUTPUT FILE TO THE NEXT. 
2       ODINO           CHAR(9)       NHTSA'S INTERNAL REFERENCE NUMBER. 
                                      THIS NUMBER MAY BE REPEATED FOR 
                                      MULTIPLE COMPONENTS.
                                      ALSO, IF LDATE IS PRIOR TO DEC 15, 2002, 
                                      THIS NUMBER MAY BE REPEATED FOR MULTIPLE 
                                      PRODUCTS OWNED BY THE SAME COMPLAINANT.
```

Some of the fields have foreign keys listed like so:

```
21      CMPL_TYPE       CHAR(4)       SOURCE OF COMPLAINT CODE:
                                        CAG  =CONSUMER ACTION GROUP
                                        CON  =FORWARDED FROM A CONGRESSIONAL OFFICE
                                        DP   =DEFECT PETITION,RESULT OF A DEFECT PETITION
                                        EVOQ =HOTLINE VOQ
                                        EWR  =EARLY WARNING REPORTING
                                        INS  =INSURANCE COMPANY
                                        IVOQ =NHTSA WEB SITE
                                        LETR =CONSUMER LETTER
                                        MAVQ =NHTSA MOBILE APP
                                        MIVQ =NHTSA MOBILE APP
                                        MVOQ =OPTICAL MARKED VOQ
                                        RC   =RECALL COMPLAINT,RESULT OF A RECALL INVESTIGATION
                                        RP   =RECALL PETITION,RESULT OF A RECALL PETITION
                                        SVOQ =PORTABLE SAFETY COMPLAINT FORM (PDF)
                                        VOQ  =NHTSA VEHICLE OWNERS QUESTIONNAIRE
```

There are [import instructions](http://www-odi.nhtsa.dot.gov/downloads/folders/Complaints/Import_Instructions.pdf) for Microsoft Access, which I don't have and would not use if I did. But I THINK this data dictionary was meant to be machine-readable.

**My question**: Is this data dictionary a standard format of some kind? I've tried to Google around, but it's hard to do so without the right terminology. I would like to import into **R**, though I'm flexible so long as it can be done programmatically.

Comment: I think you're going to have to write an R script that can extract your variables using the information in the `Type/Size` column. This is what I had to do when working with some census special tabulations.

Comment: You could read in with read.delim if it has tabs. Probably need to do some preliminary editing to get rid of the "------" junk. Then the task will be to assemble the multiline text in the fourth column. I would be cumsum-ing on the first column being something other than "" to construct a record-identifier. Oh, wait, you didn't actually provide the data? I thought you wanted that first set of records read in. You instead expected us to download a 157MB file?

Comment: Of course not! I'm fully capable of importing the tab-delimited data. I was hoping the format of the data dictionary (above) was a recognizable form (the way SAS or SPSS can output elaborate key information).